# How to space my checkboxes and the text associated with them

Tags: javascript, html

I have these check boxes that are created with a javascript function:

[image]

I would like the text to appear to the right of the checkbox and all of the text to be on one line.

Here is the javascript function and the html:

```
function receiveAnswer(response) {
//  var aSeats = document.getElementById("aSeats");
//    aSeats.options.length = 0;// clear it out
//
//   for (var i = 0; i < response.aSeats.length; i++) { // add the items back in
//    var option = aSeats.appendChild(document.createElement("option"));
//    option.value = i;
//    option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(response.aSeats[i]));
//  }

  var aSeats = document.getElementById("aSeats");
    while (aSeats.childNodes.length > 0) { // clear it out
    aSeats.removeChild(aSeats.childNodes[0]);
  }

   for (var i = 0; i < response.aSeats.length; i++) { // add the items back in
    var input = aSeats.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
    input.value = i;
    input.type = "checkbox";
    var br = aSeats.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    input.appendChild(document.createTextNode(response.aSeats[i]));
    var br = aSeats.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    var br = aSeats.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    var br = aSeats.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    var br = aSeats.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    var br = aSeats.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  }
}
```

html code:

```
<div name="aSeats" id="aSeats">
    <input type="checkbox">
</div>
```

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I love JavaScript, but most of what you're doing above could be easily achieved with simple CSS!

Comment: I know what you mean, but I'm doing this for a project and we're required to use javascript unfortunately:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a separate div to put the text in and position that div to the side of the input box, something like:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.width = 100;
div.innerHTML = text;
etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use jQuery.

### Check working example http://jsfiddle.net/FxgYz/

Comment: well I'm sorry Hussein why always flee to jquery every one have to have some experience on javascript before fleeing to any framework

Comment: Even if jQuery isn't allowed in your project (this is homework?) that code is useful to look at. Doing it without jQuery would look very similar.

Comment: Why not use jQuery. You save your self the hassle of cross browser compatibility and you can load it directly from google CDN. It will not affect your server load in a anyway. It's a smart thing to do.

Comment: well 
  i tell you why i don't , i don't like to wait for someone to invent for me something i would like to invent, by the way it yes save time for work but it keep many people who take it easy to use jquery with not knowing javascript from knowing the right way.and he just be calling him self user of technology not an inventor.
we r yes users of technology but i don't like to be a 100% one